# convert a 1-dimensional set of points to a 2-dimensional parabola with explicit embedding

Tags: machine-learning, discriminant

I am trying to rephrase to better understand concepts regarding discriminant functions for classification using explicit embedding. I report a very easy diagram found online that from 1-dimension turns points into a parabola in 2 dimensions:

[image]

Here the author shows how in one dimension it is not possible to separate the two classes and then transforms them a 2D space using the parabola

[image]

To fix the concepts better I would like to try using a small data set and manually transform the values, but I have some doubts about how to use the vector provided by the author. So I ask the courtesy if any one knows of such examples that also report the calculations